# "Код скопирован из интернета и участник не разбирается в нём"

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, тревоги

#### Описание

Почему я поднял этот вопрос?
Вот [один из вопросов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1164544). Вроде стандартный вопрос где участник просит подсказать код.

> [image]

Что вы понимайте под именем "подсказать"? Я лично понимаю как: сказать название чего-то что поможет решить проблему. Что я и сделал:

> [image]

Участник [`Yaroslav`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/352119/yaroslav) дал своеобразное решение:

> [image]

Но из-за чего мне конкретно сносило, это вот это:

> [image]

> [image]

То есть он считает, что он настолько (простите за французский) а***нный, что он может копировать с интернета что-то, кидать нам, мы должны "откоректировать" под его нужды. А у него самого времени нет.

---

Вот теперь я хочу поставить тревогу на этот вопрос. Какую из вариантов мне выбрать?

> [image]

- Невежливый или оскорбительный?
  Нет, участник конкретно так вежливо плюнул нам в лицо.
- Необходимо улучшить?
  Что улучшить тут? Код есть описание есть, заголовок стандартный.
- Необходимо удалить из-за проблем с качеством?
  Да тоже нет. Этот вопрос и в правке не нуждается.

Может мне тогда модератора позвать?

---

Если у вас нет вариантов, у меня есть. Дайте возможность отметить тревогой как: "Код скопирован из интернета и участник не разбирается в нём". Потому что если гуглить всего 3 слова из заголовка вопроса...

> [image]

...самая первая ссылка и будет мануал Unity где будет написано про `Instantiate()` в самом первом предложении:

> [image]

И весь этот поиск занимает всего минуту.

---

#### Вопрос

Я всё. Слушаю ваши идеи.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Я бы сказал, что это классический пример,
где нужно просто проголосовать
против вопроса. Сообщение рядом с кнопкой голоса
против говорит:

> Вопрос не отражает стремления разобраться; он непонятен
> или не несёт пользы

Вопрос, о котором идёт речь, явно не отражает
стремления разобраться.

Comment: @Kromster  В [традиционной типографии](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_spacing#Traditional_typesetting) для разделения предложений используются пробелы *em*-ширины.  Ваша правка использует несуществующий в *XML* *entity*, и неразрывный пробел здесь неуместен.  То, что в шрифте «*Arial*» этот пробел выглядит «некрасиво» — проблемы шрифта.  Вернул всё на место.

Comment: Недавнее увлечение? В других ваших постах такого нет ;-)

Comment: «Постоянное изменение и совершенствование», так сказать.

Comment: @Ainar-G *"For most countries, this remained the standard for published work until the 20th century."*

Answer (score 3):

Брать готовый код из интернета нормально. Просить что-то подсказать по нему - тоже.

Comment: Но просить дописать код вместо него нормально?

Comment: По причиной что у него нет времени

Comment: @Арман, личность автора вопроса не должна влиять на оценку самого вопроса.

Comment: @Grundy а разве личность влияет? Будь это не Олександр, а, скажем, John, что бы это изменило?

Comment: Так вопрошающий просит не подсказки (подсказку ему как раз дали), а "откорректировать". Т.е. по сути написать за него, то, что ему нужно.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ вот и не должно влиять, будь это даже αλεχολυτ, которому что-то лень делать. Это не должно влиять на сам вопрос: если вопрос плохой - его в любом случае нужно закрыть, несмотря на то, лень автору или нет, просит он подсказку или заново написать все.

Comment: @Эникейщик, 90% вопросов тут - это по сути написать за автора.